# Azure savings plan usage

Tags: azure, cost-management

TL/DR: How can I see which compute service is consuming what percentage of my saving plan?

I have an Azure savings plan for compute.  I have multiple App Services, an AKS cluster, and an Container App Environment.  The compute used for all three of these services is offset by the savings plan.

The problem is, I can't figure out which of those services consumes what percentage of that savings plan.  How can I use the cost analysis tool to know if my AKS nodes or my App Service compute is consuming the majority of my savings plan.

In other words, I want to reduce my spend, but I'd like to know which compute service I should focus on.  Should I right size my cluster nodes or app service plans?  I get in the end I'll do both, but having this data would help me know which one to start on

Thanks!

Comment: The close votes say that this question is apparently 'not about programming or software development' hence the downvotes. P.S. not the downvoter or close voter.

Comment: the software I write is easier to understand then my azure billing..... thanks for the comment CPlus

Answer (score 0):

The key appears to be using Amortized Cost instead of Actual Cost

looking at the previous month, filtering on

- my subscription
- Service Family (set to Compute)
- Pricing Model (set to Savings Plan)

and then grouping by the Service Name....

I can see the Amortized Cost (which more or less aligns with what I see in my invoice for my savings plan) and get a break down of the amount each service (ie VMs (ie AKS nodes) and App Service) "consumed" from the Savings Plan.

[image]